# How do I create event logging and error logging

Tags: powershell, logging, error-handling

New to Powershell, no experience, below is a simple script to move a file from one location to another, I would like to log this action and what I've done somewhere (say another file Logging.txt) but would also like to error log if the script did not run for any reason.

Searched StackOverflow but couldn't find a suitable answer

```
##########################################################################################################################################
 #Copies a single file from from one location to another location
 #Copy-item never delete extra files or folders in destination, but with -force it will overwrite if file already exists

#Copies the contents of COde_mapping.txt in the LNAT folder in a local location onto a test location on the I drive

[string]$sourceDirectory = "C:\Users\Simon.Evans\Documents\Source Data\LNAT\Code_Mapping.txt"
 [string]$destinationDirectory = "I:\Dev\BI\Projects\Powershell\Test Area\Source Data\LNAT\Code_Mapping.txt"
 Copy-item -Force -Recurse -Verbose $sourceDirectory -Destination $destinationDirectory
```

all fields to by output/appended into a single CSV/TXT for each instance the script has run

OR

Is it possible to append specific outputs created in Start-Transcript into a CSV file, an example would be I want the following fields to be appended into a csv or txt file.

Start time:

Username:

Machine:

VERBOSE:

These are all present in the Start-Transcript - Stop-Transcript, but instead of having multiple txt files each time the script has run I would like the result to be appended into just 1 txt if this at all possible.

```
##########################################################################################################################################
#Copies a single file from from one location to another location
#Copy-item never delete extra files or folders in destination, but with  -force it will overwrite if file already exists

#Copies the contents of COde_mapping.txt in the LNAT folder in a local location onto a test location on the I drive

$datevar = get-date -Format ("yyyyMMdd") 
$timevar = Get-date -Format ("hhmmss")
$varfullpath = "C:\Users\Simon.Evans\Documents\ReferenceData_logfile_$datevar_$timevar.txt"

Start-Transcript -Path $varfullpath

Write-Output $datevar
Write-Output $timevar
write-output $varfullpath

[string]$sourceDirectory  = "C:\Users\Simon.Evans\Documents\Source Data\LNAT\Code_Mapping.txt"
[string]$destinationDirectory = "I:\Dev\BI\Projects\Powershell\Test Area\Source Data\LNAT\Code_Mapping.txt"
Copy-item -Force -Recurse -Verbose $sourceDirectory -Destination $destinationDirectory

Stop-Transcript
```

************* UPDATE 21/06/2019 9:22am (UK) *************

This is what I now have and it works, however now I want to try and add a TRY CATCH and diplay the Error transaction if it fails and contunie to do as below if successful, again is this possible and how would I go about doing this please

```
$varfullpath = "C:\Users\Simon.Evans\Documents\ReferenceData__logfile.txt" 
Start-Transcript -Path $varfullpath -Append                                                            
write-output $varfullpath
[string]$sourceDirectory  = "C:\Users\Simon.Evans\Documents\Source Data\LNAT\Code_Mapping.txt"
[string]$destinationDirectory = "I:\Dev\BI\Projects\Powershell\Test Area\Source Data\LNAT\Code_Mapping.txt"
Copy-item -Force  -Verbose $sourceDirectory -Destination $destinationDirectory
Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: Since you put a full path and filename in the variables `$sourceDirectory` and `$destinationDirectory` (therefore copying a single file), you don't need the `-Recurse` switch.

Answer (score 1):

Use the -append parameter in the start-transcript commandlet to append the logfile instead of creating a new one.

Comment: does the -Append go after Start-Transcript, sorry but only been using Powershell 1 couple of days

Comment: Yes, start-transcript path C:\file\path\log.txt -append

Comment: I had an error : Stop-Transcript : An error occurred stopping transcription: The host is not currently transcribing.

Comment: I don't get that here using your exact script, but you should remove the 3 apostrophes after stop-transcript.

Comment: Thanks that works but really want to be clever and just output / Append just 4 fields into a txt so each time I run the scrip just one row of 4 columns gets appended, just exploring if possible

Comment: You can, but then you have to build your own logging instead of using start-transcript. This commandlet logs your entire powershell session and not just what you are doing. Search for errorhandling on powershell, like with try/catch for example.